# Does not display the PDF files in listview thumbnail format c# 2008

Tags: c#

im trying to display the PDF files in the listview thumnail like windows explorer. I have not any idea about this.

How to display the pdf files. plz suggest some idea.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to programically create the thumbnail by utalising, for example:

[Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/)

or the [Adobe Acrobat SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/)

There are various articles on the web discussing the merits of each.